# Can't add index to persisted computed column because it is "of a type that is invalid for use as a key"

Tags: sql, sql-server, clr

I have a table like this with a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE PhoneNumbers
(
    [PhoneNumberID] int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered,
    [Number] varchar(20), /* Entire number, like (800) 555-5000 */
    [Digits] AS dbo.RegExReplace(Number, '[^0-9]', '') PERSISTED  /* Like 8005555000 */
)
```

It's created fine, and the `Digits` column works great as expected, BUT it doesn't seem to behave as a "PERSISTED" column.  When I do a query with `Digits` in the WHERE clause it's VERY slow.  When I try to add an index to the Digits column I get: `Column 'Digits' in table 'PhoneNumbers' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.`

It seems like that column isn't really being treated as PERSISTED and is being recomputed on every query and won't let me add an index.

The RegExReplace is a C# CLR function defined as follows:

```
[SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]
public static SqlString RegExReplace(SqlString expression, SqlString pattern, SqlString replace)
```

Any ideas on how to get that `Digits` column to act like a persisted column or allow me to add an index?!

Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't design like that. I wouldn't store anything but digits, and I would use the front end to enforce any patterns. It's overdesign, IMO.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right, but this is a legacy database that has many many records already in it and many points of entry for these records.  I thought this might be an easier patch to get at just the numbers without having to change code in 10 different places.  (The "Digits" column is actually a new column, not part of the original design)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try a CAST:

```
CREATE TABLE PhoneNumbers
(
    [PhoneNumberID] int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered,
    [Number] varchar(20), /* Entire number, like (800) 555-5000 */
    [Digits] AS CAST(dbo.RegExReplace(Number, '[^0-9]', '') AS VARCHAR(20)) PERSISTED  /* Like 8005555000 */
)
```

I believe that the problem is your CLR function is returning SqlString which ends up being nvarchar(4000) or similar - not indexable.

It's kind of a known "problem" with computed columns that the datatype is inferred from the expression.  Mainly an issue with strings and "helper functions" which take varchar(max) and also with decimal operations where precision changes due to the calculations.

I have a little rule where I always CAST - it makes it explicit and avoids any ambiguity.  Generally, columns which are known to be small should be explicitly small - varchar(max) seems to have a lot of performance overhead - even if you pass through a function which returns varchar(max) and takes varchar(max), cast back to the size you know, because it will perform a lot better.

Comment: Wow... Awesome answer!  I was actually searching for how I could declare that computed column to be of a certain type, but didn't consider a simple cast.  It actually DOES solve the "invalid for a key column" error and I can add an index, but the performance is still terrible when searching on that column?  I'm currently considering biting the bullet and redesigning the "Number" column to contain only digits.  Thanks so much!  You rock!

Comment: @JerSchneid I'm not sure why performance is bad - check your execution plan, of course.  Once the column is persisted, it shouldn't be calling your CLR function.  Perhaps it's not using the index first due to some other things in the query?  Is your index containing that persisted column covering?

Comment: The execution plan doesn't seem to give me any info... Stone cold simple queries like "SELECT * FROM from PhoneNumbers WHERE Digits='8005552000'" don't use any indexes I create that include column.  Don't know why?

Comment: @JerSchneid You'd have to post the index creation DDL etc.  Unless the column is first in the index, that simple query probably wouldn't use it.